# How to calculate derivative composed vector function

Tags: calculus

I need to find the following derivative
$\frac{\partial(\frac{1}{(|\vec r_{1}(t_{1})-\vec r_{2}(t_{2})|)})}{\partial t_{1}}$

when $\vec r_1(t_1)$ is a vector function depended in $t_1$
and $\vec r_1(t_1)$ is a vector function depended in $t_2$ but not in $t_1$

I try to go to a cartesian representation, but I cannot find expression that including only $\vec r_1(t_1),\vec r_2(t_2)$ ,their magnitudes and derivatives of $t_1$

Answer (score 1):

As $|\vec r_{1}(t_{1})-\vec r_{2}(t_{2})| = \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2+(z_1-z_2)^2}$,

$$\frac{\partial(\frac{1}{(|\vec r_{1}(t_{1})-\vec r_{2}(t_{2})|)})}{\partial t_{1}} = \frac{\partial(\frac{1}{(|\vec r_{1}(t_{1})-\vec r_{2}(t_{2})|)})}{\partial(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2+(z_1-z_2)^2}\frac{\partial(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2+(z_1-z_2)^2}{\partial t_1}$$
$$\implies \frac{\partial(\frac{1}{(|\vec r_{1}(t_{1})-\vec r_{2}(t_{2})|)})}{\partial t_{1}} = \frac{-1}{2(|\vec r_{1}(t_{1})-\vec r_{2}(t_{2})|)^\frac{3}{2}}(2x_1x_1'+2y_1y_1'+2z_1z_1')$$

Comment: But how to express $(x_1x_1'+y_1y'_1+z_1z'_1)$ with $r_1(t_1)$?

Comment: That is equal to $r_1(t_1)\cdot r'_1(t_1)$

Comment: did you mean $\vec r_1(t_1) \cdot \frac{\partial(\vec r_1(t_1))}{\partial t_1}$?